# How I can retrieve webcam info in python?

Tags: python, webcam

I need to retrieve the number of webcams instaled in my system and the brand, manufacturer, device id, etc., of the webcam.
Is there any way to do that in Python, and independent of the operating system?

Answer (score 0):

There's no truly cross-platform solution, but on Linux you can use `os.popen('lsusb')` (or something along those lines) and then just scrape the screen (using grep or something else). For finding out on Windows, you can try using a TWAIN binding for Python (it's the Windows webcam protocol, a Python binding exists [here](http://twainmodule.sourceforge.net/), but it's not actively maintained). [VideoCapture](http://videocapture.sourceforge.net/) might have what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial solution, which is to use the command:

```
v4l2-ctl --list-devices
```

But only works on Linux, but on Windows I have no way of detecting the amount and the name of the installed webcams.